# How do I write a BeautifulSoup strainer that only parses objects with certain text between the tags?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I want to have more efficient parsing so I was reading about SoupStrainer objects.  I created a custom one to help me parse only the elements I need ...

```
def my_custom_strainer(self, elem, attrs):
    for attr in attrs:
        print("attr:" + attr + "=" + attrs[attr])
    if elem == 'div' and 'class' in attr and attrs['class'] == "score":
        return True
    elif elem == "span" and elem.text == re.compile("my text"):
        return True

article_stat_page_strainer = SoupStrainer(self.my_custom_strainer)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser", parse_only=article_stat_page_strainer)
```

One of the conditions is I only want to parse "span" elements whose text matches a certain pattern.  Hence the

```
elem == "span" and elem.text == re.compile("my text")
```

clause.  However, this results in an

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

error when I try and run the above.  What's the proper way to write my strainer?

Comment: It seems like your 'elem' variable is already a string not a Soup object that's why you can't parse it

Comment: Yes, so what do I need to do to get the outcome I want?

Comment: What @ElvirMuslic is saying is there are `NavigableString` object instance (in this case) which represents exactly what the name implies versus actual tag encapsulaton with all of the methods / attributes you're familiar with. You can simply check the instance type. i.e. - `isinstance(object, NavigableString)` and `isinstance(object, Tag)`

Comment: You mean apply the "isinstance" to the first argument passed to the custom function given to the strainer?

Comment: It may not be possible to filter based on tag name/attributes _and_ text, because of BeautifulSoup's internal structure. Tag name/attributes are parsed in `.handle_starttag()` while the text is parsed in `.handle_data()` and `.endData()`, and SoupStrainer can't access them both at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR;** No, this is currently not easily possible in BeautifulSoup (modification of BeautifulSoup and SoupStrainer objects would be needed).

**Explanation:**

The problem is that the Strainer-passed function gets called on `handle_starttag()` method. As you can guess, you only have values in the opening tag (eg. element name and attrs).

[https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/**init**.py#L524](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/__init__.py#L524)

```
if (self.parse_only and len(self.tagStack) <= 1
    and (self.parse_only.text
     or not self.parse_only.search_tag(name, attrs))):
return None
```

And as you can see, if your Strainer function returns False, the element gets discarded immediately, without having chance to take the inner text inside into consideration (unfortunately).

On the other hand if you add "text" to search.

```
SoupStrainer(text="my text")
```

it will start to search inside the tag for text, but this doesn't have context of element or attributes - you can see the irony :/

and combining it together will just find nothing. And you can't even access parent like shown here in find function:
https://gist.github.com/RichardBronosky/4060082

So currently Strainers are just good to filter on elements/attrs. You would need to change a lot of Beautiful soup code to get that working.

If you really need this, I suggest inheriting BeautifulSoup and SoupStrainer objects and modifying their behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you try to loop along soup elements in `my_custom_strainer` method.

In order to do so, you could do it as follows:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser", parse_only=article_stat_page_strainer)
my_custom_strainer(soup, attrs)
```

Then slightly modify `my_custom_strainer` to meet something like:

```
def my_custom_strainer(soup, attrs):
  for attr in attrs:
    print("attr:" + attr + "=" + attrs[attr])
  for d in soup.findAll(['div','span']):
    if d.name == 'span' and 'class' in attr and attrs['class'] == "score":
      return d.text # meet your needs here
   elif d.name == 'span' and d.text == re.compile("my text"):
      return d.text # meet your needs here
```

This way you can access the soup objects iteratively.

Comment: But isn't the custom function passed to soup strainer always going to get passed the element and the attrs (e.g. what is passed to "strainer = SoupStrainer(...)"?

Comment: not really useful if you want to accomplish what you pointed out your question

Comment: What's not really useful?

Comment: Be at peace my brother.  There are way worse things to get angry about than some random guy asking a question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I recently created a lxml / BeautifulSoup parser for html files, which also searches between specific tags.

The function I wrote opens up a your operating system's file manager and allows you to select the specifi html file to parse.

```
def openFile(self):
    options = QFileDialog.Options()

    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "",
                                              "All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
    if fileName:
        file = open(fileName)
        data = file.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
        for item in soup.find_all('strong'):
            results.append(float(item.text))
    print('Score =', results[1])
    print('Fps =', results[0])
```

You can see that the tag i specified was 'strong', and i was trying to find the text within that tag.

Hope I could help in someway.