# In BeautifulSoup, what's the proper way to use a strainer with lxml parsing?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, lxml

I'm using Beautiful Soup 4 and Python 3.8.  I want to parse only certain elements from an HTML page, so I decided to use a strainer like so ...

```
req = urllib2.Request(full_url, headers=settings.HDR)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml", parse_only=DictionaryService.idiom_match_strainer)

,,,

    @staticmethod
    def idiom_match_strainer(elem, attrs):
        if elem == 'ul' and 'class' in attrs and attrs['class'] == 'idiKw':
            return True
        return False
```

Unfortunately when I try and parse any URL (https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/testing is an example), I'm getting the below error

```
Internal Server Error: /ajax/get_hints
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/dictionary_project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/dictionary_project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/dictionary_project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/dictionary_project/dictionary/views.py", line 194, in get_hints
    objects = s.get_hints(article)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/dictionary_project/dictionary/services/article_service.py", line 398, in get_hints
    idioms = DictionaryService.get_idioms(word)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/dictionary_project/dictionary/services/dictionary_service.py", line 75, in get_idioms
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml", parse_only=DictionaryService.idiom_match_strainer)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/dictionary_project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 281, in __init__
    self._feed()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/dictionary_project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 342, in _feed
    self.builder.feed(self.markup)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/dictionary_project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/builder/_lxml.py", line 287, in feed
    self.parser.feed(markup)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1242, in lxml.etree._FeedParser.feed
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1364, in lxml.etree._FeedParser.feed
  File "src/lxml/parsertarget.pxi", line 148, in lxml.etree._TargetParserContext._handleParseResult
  File "src/lxml/parsertarget.pxi", line 136, in lxml.etree._TargetParserContext._handleParseResult
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 314, in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored
  File "src/lxml/saxparser.pxi", line 389, in lxml.etree._handleSaxTargetStartNoNs
  File "src/lxml/saxparser.pxi", line 404, in lxml.etree._callTargetSaxStart
  File "src/lxml/parsertarget.pxi", line 80, in lxml.etree._PythonSaxParserTarget._handleSaxStart
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/dictionary_project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/builder/_lxml.py", line 220, in start
    self.soup.handle_starttag(name, namespace, nsprefix, attrs)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/dictionary_project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 582, in handle_starttag
    and (self.parse_only.text
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Is there a different way I should be using the strainer?

Comment: What are the parameters passed to `idiom_match_strainer`?

Comment: I was under the impression from their docs -- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ that the arguments had to always be element and attributes, whch is why I included the two in my strainer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54838079/how-do-i-write-a-beautifulsoup-strainer-that-only-parses-objects-with-certain-te

Comment: @QHarr is that a duplicate?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I think it could be

Comment: The question referenced is asking how to write a strainer that only parses text between certain tags.  My question regards how to parse tags (no text) using an lxml parser.

Comment: @Dave - If you know you are only interested in a single tag, you can pass its name to iter() to have it filter for you. Starting with lxml 3.0, you can also pass more than one tag to intercept on multiple tags during iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should suffice to use the SoupStrainer from the package:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import SoupStrainer

html = '<html><body><section><ul class="foo"><li>a<li>b</ul><ul><li>1<li>2</ul></section><ul class="foo"><li>c<li>d</ul></body></html>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml", parse_only=SoupStrainer('ul', class_='foo'))

print(soup.prettify())
```

gives

```
<ul class="foo">
 <li>
  a
 </li>
 <li>
  b
 </li>
</ul>
<ul class="foo">
 <li>
  c
 </li>
 <li>
  d
 </li>
</ul>
```

So for your call you want `parse_only=SoupStrainer('ul', class_='idiKw')` I think.